# Automating some tasks in cPanel

Tags: php, shell, cpanel

I would like to automate the creation of subdomains and databases in cPanel. Where might I start for something like this? I would like a simple frontend interface in PHP where I might can enter a couple of variables and automate the setup of, well, subdomains and databases, possibly by running some shell commands. Any suggestions where I should start?

Comment: cpanel's create account does most of this

Comment: Yes, I know cpanel allows you to do this. My question was regarding automating this process.

Comment: Yes, thank you, however if you do not have any comments about scripting actions done in cPanel, please refrain from posting on this question.

Comment: i don't think you understand what cpanel is.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone else interested in scripting out cPanel functions, for the purpose of automating tasks done in cPanel, while still keeping everything easily maintained from cPanel's interface, here is the way to go:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/vief/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome

cPanel and WHM have an API that allows you to do these things. I hope it's useful for someone in the future.